# HTML5 date input field validation needs to be disabled for the current value

Tags: html, date

I have a HTML5 date input field and it may have a pre populated value. I want the 'min' attribute set to 'todays date' but do not want to throw an error on submit if the date field already has a value that is a previous date, and is untouched. But in case user decides to change the date, the calendar should disable everything before today. Is that possible?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dirac-gsvqd?file=/src/App.js

The calendar should be as in the code. But the error thrown on submit should not happen, if the date is not changed. Currently, error is thrown on submit with no change

Comment: You will probably have to code an onChange listener that will return false if the date is *changed* to a date before today, which wouldn't pose problem when submitting a date that already was before today

Comment: That wont work, Have added a codesandbox. If I exclude min attribute, calendar will show previous dates. But if I include min attribute, even with no change error is thrown on submit